# How do I create a vector of mode='Date'

Tags: r

I want to use the line below in a function

```
datehit <- vector(mode="Date",length(vectordiagdate))
```

but I receive an error

```
> Error in vector(mode = "Date", length(vectordiagdate)) : 
  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'Date'.
```

I shall use the dates later with `datediff`.

What is wrong, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a storage mode of `Date`.

Date is a `class`:

```
date.vec <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+10, 1) # date vector example
mydate   <- as.Date("1970-01-01")  # class conversion from character to date
```

Using your example (loosely):

```
as.vector(data.frame(x = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+10,1)), mode = "list")
```

> ```
>             x
> 1  2016-07-11
> 2  2016-07-12
> 3  2016-07-13
> 4  2016-07-14
> 5  2016-07-15
> 6  2016-07-16
> 7  2016-07-17
> 8  2016-07-18
> 9  2016-07-19
> 10 2016-07-20
> 11 2016-07-21
> ```

```
datehit <- as.Date(datehit$x)
```

Valid storage modes are:

- "logical"
- "integer"
- "double"
- "complex"
- "raw"
- "character"
- "list"
- "expression"
- "name"
- "symbol"
- "function"

Comment: You missed a few. See `?typeof` upon which both `mode` and `storage.mode` are based

Answer (score 1):

If you want something similar to how one often uses `vector()`, as a template object to fill in, then you could do

```
as.Date(rep(NA, length = 10))

> (foo <- as.Date(rep(NA, length = 10)))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> class(foo)
[1] "Date"
```

We can't use `NULL` as the object to `rep` as that throws a warning to annoy us as `as.Date` chokes on `NULL` too.